# How to add numbers only if some other cell matches a particular criteria in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api

**situation**

A spreadsheet to maintain accounts.

A form as so: [The form](http://goo.gl/3Wk2V)

**What I want to do**

I want to add the value in the column D if it has Type of transaction = Credit and If it has type of transaction = debit then I want to subtract it from the total. I am finding this total inside the spreadsheet itself. So I think `SUMIF(...,...,...)` will be used but I am not sure.

[Spreadsheet](http://goo.gl/ijWOz) for reference.

**I guess:**

The criteria could be what is the first letter of the cell in column C which is in the same row as the cell now being considered which belongs to column D. If it is of the form `C*` then it is credit if it is of the form `D*` then it is a debit transaction. But I am unable to find out how to apply this condition.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The SUMIF criteria in Spreadsheet works as follows:

```
=SUMIF(range, criteria, sum_range)
```

whereby range is the range from which you want to match (C column in your example, which has Debit/Credit)

Criteria = what should match (Debit or Credit based on the formula in your example)

Sum_range = The Column that needs to be summed - (D column in your example)

So your formula should be somewhat

```
=SUMIF(C1:C1000,"D"&"*",D1:D1000) for Debit
=SUMIF(C1:C1000,"C"&"*",D1:D1000) for Credit
```

Note: you can use "Debit" or "Credit" in place of "D"&"*" or "C"&"*" respectively.

Comment: This was very helpful even though the OP's spreadsheet is gone from Google Drive and we haven't got a reference of it anymore.